# Use checkbox as togglebutton in expander

Tags: wpf, checkbox, expander, togglebutton

Im quite new to wpf and have to following problem.

I need to create a List (i am using a listbox) of items that can be expanded (expander).
The problem is, that they can be expanded, only if they have been 'selected'. 
Each listboxitem should have a checkbox and some text.

So very basic example to illustrate what i mean:

```
<listbox>
<item>(checkbox) John Doe</item>
<item>(checkbox) Mike Murray</item>
</listbox>
```

If any (so multiple is allowed) of the checkboxes in the listbox are checked, then 
the item expands showing more data.

Again an example:

```
<listbox>
<item>
   (checkbox-checked) John Doe
   Some extra data shown in expanded area
</item>
<item>
   (checkbox-unchecked) Mike Murray</item>
</listbox>
```

I cant get a expander to use a checkbox as 'togglebutton'.

Could anyone help me out? Some example code would be very welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Expander">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Expander">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <CheckBox
                                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                />
                            <ContentControl
                                x:Name="body"
                                Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                />
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="body" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </ListBox.Resources>

    <Expander Header="One">
        Content one
    </Expander>

    <Expander Header="Two">
        Content two
    </Expander>
</ListBox>
```

I've defined a `Style` here that changes the `Template` of any `Expander` controls to which the `Style` is applied. (And since I've put the `Style` in the `ListBox.Resources` it'll automatically apply to an `Expander` controls in the list.)

The trick to getting the `CheckBox` to work is that when you put it (or indeed any `ToggleButton` based control) into an `Expander` template, you need to use a data binding configured with its `RelativeSource` set to the `TemplatedParent`. This enables two-way binding - it means that not only does the `CheckBox` reflect the current state of the expander, it is also able to *change* the current state.

Comment: Hi Ian, 

thank you very much for your reply.
I have your example working and also it working (to some extent) in my application.

I have another question and hope you could help with it too.

Given the setup of the original question, a Listbox with a checkbox as togglebutton, I use it to display a list of customers.

My next problem is the following:
Some of the customers need to be pre-selected (for example: if a customer is > 18 years old, default = checked, when the form is loaded)

Can I do this (and is it possible through binding?)

Comment: Yes, definitely possible. I'm assuming you're using an ItemTemplate in practice, and that the Expander is in there. (And if you aren't you should!) In your ViewModel, you'll want a per-item viewmodel class, so your main viewmodel can expose a list it per-item viewmodels to act as the ItemSource of your list. And then, just bind the IsExpanded property of the Expander to a boolean property of the per-item viewmodel.

Comment: I dont have a per-item viemodel class for the items in the listbox (yet), I will try that.
What i have now is to bind the IsExpanded property of the Expander with a property in the viewmodel of my current form/view, but somehow I can't access/find that property. When I write:
IsExpanded="True", it works perfectly. When I write IsExpanded="{Binding Path=PropertyNameThatGivesBooleanForSelected}" (or without Path=) it doesn't work. The property is never read. I will try a per-item viewmodel as you said, but I actually expected what i have now also to work.

Comment: I just created a per-item viewmodel as you said, and it works perfect now! Thank very much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

All you need to add a check box in the header is this code:

```
            <telerik:RadExpander.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0">Legend</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </telerik:RadExpander.Header>
```

I am using Rad Control, The same can be done using the standard expander